# retina macbook автоматически увеличивает масштаб страницы и отображает планшетную версию вместо десктопной

Tags: javascript, html, css

retina macbook автоматически увеличивает масштаб страницы и отображает планшетную версию сайта с шириной контейнера 940px вместо того чтобы отображать десктопную версию с шириной контейнера 1300px.
как можно решить эту проблему так, чтобы отображалась десктопная версия, ведь на retina ширина экрана ~2500px.
переделывать сайт не хочется, так как там примерно 30 страниц и если уменьшить ширину контайнера, то все развалиться.
может вожможно как нибудь указать браузеру чтобы увеличивал страницу чуть меньше и помещалась десктопная версия?

http://tea-mail.helixweb.ru/pages/home/home.html

Answer (score 0):

Ретина не увеличивает масштаб. В таких экранах применяется большая плотность пикселей. Вы возможно слышали про `device-pixel-ratio`.

Так вот, что бы сайт правильно отображался на таких экранах необходимо добавить `meta` тэг в `head`.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: есть такой meta tag
http://joxi.ru/KAge6EougaB7Xm

Comment: @Hovsep, Вы пробовали чистить кеш браузера, после добавления тега? При эмуляции retina у меня все отображается верно.

Comment: да этот тег был с самого начало, проблема не в кеше.
вы можете сказать какой у вас конкретно ноутбук и сделать скриншот экрана с открытой страницей?

Comment: @Hovsep, Экран значения не иммеет использую Chrome с эмуляцией DPR: 2, как у ретин.

Answer (score -1):

попробуйте использовать следующее:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {     
  /* For Retina-Display */ 
  ...
}
```

Comment: Вопрос не о том, как изменить разрешение монитора, а о том как отображать на устройстве.

Comment: если бы вы заглянули на сайт вы бу увидели код: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> который вы и советуете.

Comment: на macbook air 13 с разрешением экрана 1440x900 отображается десктопная версия, то есть на 1440x900 все нормаьно сейчас. а почему тогда на macbook retina отображается планшетная версия если там тоже разрешение 1440x900?

Comment: @АртурШмаков, и тем не менее это правильный ответ. Значит проблемы с браузером, а не с разметкой.

Comment: ну это понятно, css media query, и что мне писать в нем?)
я же написал в вопросе, что не могу менять сайт.